# Get Bitmap from Universal Image Loader onItemClick (GridView)

Tags: android, bitmap, universal-image-loader

I am using [Nostra's UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to display images in a `GridView.` However, in the example provided, he gets the image by passing the position of the array at the moment an item has been clicked:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, DoneDiscardActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("pos", position + "");
    startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Is there a way to receive the `Bitmap` to the clicked position?

Something like this?

```
loader.displayImage(imagesA[position], holder.image, op,
    new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bitmap = loadedImage; 
    }
    });
```

But, loading the actual clicked image?

I tried without success:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    Drawable d = iv.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
});
```

Comment: Have you get clicked image properly??

Comment: Yes. The implementation works fine. It is loading perfectly.

Comment: the statement `Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);` will not give you image of `ImageView`. it simply creates a `Bitmap` whose width and height equal to width and height of image in `ImageView`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can by this way in your `OnItemClick` listener..

```
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    Drawable drawable = iv.getDrawable();
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable d = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        Bitmap bitmap = d.getBitmap();//Required bitmap
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this also.

```
BitmapDrawable bmdr = (BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable();
Bitmap mybmp = bmdr.getBitmap();
```

***Note:*** BitmapDrawable constructor is deprecated also.

Comment: Yes i just missed method word in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Both answers work. But, I will have to mark his as the right one because he was first. You deserve a vote though :)